# Create one rule to maintain multiple URLs

Tags: iis, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

Windows Server 2012

I have 1 IIS container with 4 different URLs for one domain and 2 domains in total as below (set with the bindings)

```
www.site1.com
site1.com
www.site1.co.uk
site1.co.uk

www.site2.com
site2.com
www.site2.co.uk
site2.co.uk
```

www.site1.com - is the primary domain, meaning any combination of the URLs above must take the user to www.site1.com or www.site2.com

Below is the config i have for site 1 but site 2 is essentially the same. www.Site2.com not listed for brevity

```
<rule name="site1CoUk" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="site1.co.uk" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.site1.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
<rule name="site1WwwCoUk" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.site1.co.uk" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.site1.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
<rule name="site1Com" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="site1.com" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.site1.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
```

Everything seems to work but is there a way to reduce the configuration so i can maintain it within one rule (or 2 rules if i add in the www.site2.com). So i did something like this

```
<rule name="site1CoUk" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="site1.co.uk" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.site1.co.uk" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="site1.com" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.site1.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
```

but this doesnt work as soon as i add the second HTTP_HOST pattern.

The main reason is as i add more URLS it would easier to maintain under a one rule rather than adding a new rule each time round? Eventually the site would become https so i assume i could change the URL.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#rule-conditions Use `logicalGrouping="MatchAny"` (because the default is `MatchAll`).

Comment: Should i add this as an addition to the second config i provided with the 3 HTTP_HOST sites? Or another separate entry somewhere else?

Comment: Let Google give you examples on how `logicalGrouping` is used by others, and you can find a lot.

Comment: Thanks..... i have that working. Could I just replace the url (against action type) with https or do i need to create another rule? Unfortunately i cant test this as i dont have an SSL cert so be great if i can an idea of whats involved

Comment: You'd better create a separate rule if you want HTTP to HTTPS redirection. Messing up too much in one rule is never a good idea.

Comment: If you want to put this as an answer I can mark it as one

Comment: You can post your answer and accept it.